# Angular 4 calls WCF REST twice

Tags: angular, angular-http, wcf-rest, angular-observable

I am writing a demo app which will call WCF rest service from my Angular 4 application using HTTP service post. 
I can post my data successfully to my service method (operationcontract). 
But it calls my service two times and in second time it hits the service method. 
First time it just hits the `Global.asax` file. 
Is this how http post of angular works ?

Following is the service call:

[image]

Following is the operation contract or rest service method:

[image]

Following is the service implementation:

[image]

Following is the `Global.asax` code:

This Global.asax code is getting hit twice, i am not getting why ?

[image]

Following is the Chrome dev toolbar Network tab detail, it is calling WCF rest twice.

[image]

Fallowing is the chrome network request and response:
First Call that is 'option' call:
[image]

Second call that is post call:

[image]

Comment: Instead of sharing screenshots/images, please share your code here. For example, in my country imgur.com is forbidden (don't ask why :) ) and I cannot see what is in the images. And of course, people cannot search text in images, right?

Comment: it looks like you are using CORS. So can you confirm (by looking at the chrome dev tools network tab or otherwise) that the first call is not an OPTIONS call?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

Answer (score 2):

As Ethan already said: you are using CORS. So the webbrowser calls the endpoint with an OPTIONS request first.

BUT this won't call the Rest-API twice (you can check this with backend logging or just breakpoints in your backend).
I think your frontend is running in dev-mode (you can check this in your browser-log -> angular creates a logging entry if it's running in dev-mode).

In dev-mode angular **double checks** every user-interaction and (imho) every http-call in dev-mode to prevent timing- and "value changed after it has been checked"-bugs.

Comment: Hi Tobias,Ethan,
Please see last edited option in query. You can see chrome dev tool bar events

Comment: yeah, it is calling twice. there is still no clue which http method these are. Could be the OPTIONS-method for cors and POST for the "real" call

Comment: btw: you don't need `JSON.stringify(servers)` if your backend supports json-post-body

Comment: if rest is getting called twice ? This will be a performance issue. My team's architect will not allow me to do so.
IS this the case for all rest APIs ? Spring rest, Java Rest - in all these cases it will call twice ?
Is this how it works or its my code which is culprit ?

Comment: As said by @Tobias, two request does not mean two API call. If you open the first request details, you will probably see the HTTP Method set to OPTIONS. This means Angular is running CORS.

Comment: You can read more about CORS here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: "Application_BeginRequest" is getting called twice so that means two API calls.

Comment: as i said "IMHO". i'm not sure if angular is doing the request two times.
CORS is forcing the browser to do an OPTIONS-call.

i'm sure that angular is calling every user interaction twice in DEV-MODE.

Comment: couldn't you just debug your backend what the first call is doing? is this just a options call or not? please provide more information. you can just show the details of the request in chrome dev console.

Comment: the first call is an OPTIONS request. the webbrowser is forced to do that, because you are requesting a backend which has not the same protocol+host/ip+port as your frontend. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing for more information.

Comment: so in the options request there is no big data transfer. the webbrowser only asks the backend if he is allowed to do the request inside your frontend application